# Microsoft UWP Using Unity3D - Getting Errors Compiling Ad Plugin

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, uwp, store

Hi I keep getting errors when compiling the plugin.  The plugin is supposed to be derived from here - https://github.com/Microsoft/unityplugins, and I can't find any plugins that are already compiled.  The error I keep getting when trying to compile the ads plugin is:

```
C:\users\brett\Desktop\Microsoft Ads\unityplugins\MainProjects\CommonSource\Microsoft.UnityPlugins.Common\Utils.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\users\brett\Desktop\Microsoft Ads\unityplugins\MainProjects\Win10\Microsoft.UnityPlugins.Common\Microsoft.UnityPlugins.Common.csproj]
```

I tried looking for a similar problem with a solution but it seems that noone else is having this issue, even though the code is run straight from downloading it without modification.

Answer (score 0):

The plugins in this repository haven't been maintained for some time according to the issue list and lack of pull requests.

It seems it is now easier to implement the `Microsoft Advertising` into your game manually using XAML. When you generate the UWP solution for the app, it will create a `MainPage.xaml` file for you. Here you can put the native `AdControl` from the [Microsoft Advertising SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftAdvertisingSDK).

You can [see in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Manual/windowsstore-projecttypes.html) that you may safely modify the file without having to worry about the changes being overwritten by the next build.

Comment: Thanks Martin I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make windows ads works inside unity for anyone who still looking for an answer.

To summarise : just add IMicrosoftAdsBridge.cs and MicrsoftAdsEditor.cs to your unity project, adding a custom script ([see repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/unityplugins/issues/21#issuecomment-195725950)), then calling RequestAd() before ShowAd().

On visual studio windows phone or windows project you must add another custom script ([see repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/unityplugins/issues/21#issuecomment-195725950)) called MicrosoftAdsBridge.cs, and finally add this code ([see repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/unityplugins/issues/21#issuecomment-195725950)) to app.xaml.cs before Window.Current.Activate();